# Samsung Smart TV Orsay Model Development with Javascript

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

currently I want to develop application for Samsung Smart TV Legacy (Orsay model), what I knew was that is 2 ways for developing app for Samsung Smart TV, the first one is by use AppsFramework and the other one is by use Javascript.

My question is, does anyone know where I can find a reference to develop an app for Samsung TV model Orsay with Javascript?for AppsFramework, I understand we can use **Scene** to move from one page to another page (even I still do not understand, how to pass a parameter), but for the Javascript, I cannot find a way how to develop an app with multiple page?or does Samsung Smart TV only support SPA (Single Page Application) for the Javascript version?

Please help me, if anyone knew any references or maybe have an experienced for this Samsung TV Orsay development, if you have a small sample for how to develop multipage application with Javascript on Samsung Smart TV, I would really appreciate it.

Regards.

I have tried to read the docs on Samsung Official Website here :

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/legacy/overview.html

But honestly, I'm still don't know how to implement a multiple page with Javascript version.